# Java - Deserialize nested Json Object to Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have some probleme to deserialize some nested Json.

The json : [Json Link Here](https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json) To deserialize :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ListRandomBixi bixi = objectMapper.readValue(url, ListRandomBixi.class);
```

And the two classes :

```
class ListRandomBixi{
@JsonProperty("stations")
ArrayList<RandomBixi> arrayBixi;
@JsonProperty("schemeSuspended")
boolean schemeSuspended;
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
long timeStanp;

@JsonCreator
public ListRandomBixi(@JsonProperty("stations") ArrayList<RandomBixi> arrayBixi, @JsonProperty("schemeSuspended") boolean schemeSuspended, @JsonProperty("timestamp") long timeStanp) {
  this.arrayBixi = arrayBixi;
  this.schemeSuspended = schemeSuspended;
  this.timeStanp = timeStanp;
}
      getters & setters....
}
class RandomBixi {
@JsonProperty("id")
int id;
@JsonProperty("s")
String nom;
@JsonProperty("n")
int idTerminal;
@JsonProperty("st")
int etatStation;
@JsonProperty("b")
boolean bloque;
@JsonProperty("su")
boolean suspendue;
@JsonProperty("m")
boolean hs;
@JsonProperty("lu")
int lu;
@JsonProperty("lc")
int lc;
@JsonProperty("la")
String latitude;
@JsonProperty("lo")
String longitude;
@JsonProperty("da")
int borneDispo;
@JsonProperty("dx")
int dx;
@JsonProperty("ba")
int bixiDispo;
@JsonProperty("bx")
int bx;

  getters ans setters....
}
```

I'm getting this error : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized Type: [null]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of `blabla1` and `blabla2` are also text. But you are declare class field is `boolean` and `long`. This cause the error. Let's change the type of `blabla1` and `blabla2` to `String`

Comment: Sorry i just edited the json. Now is the version i have ^^

Comment: With that JSON I don't believe that you got the error `JsonMappingException: Unrecognized Type: [null]`. Did you try to use debugger?

Comment: I edited again my code to give you a more precise view. I tried debugging but the debugger blocks on this line : `ListRandomBixi bixi = objectMapper.readValue(url, ListRandomBixi.class);` and if i try to go further into the problem i can just find the START_OBJECT that is : '{' ...

Comment: Now you have a completely difference json and parse class, still the same error? You should start all again with the question to make it easy to understand for help. Not only me but others too

Comment: I still got the same error. I just posted back a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260691/java-deserialize-nested-json-to-object
Thank you