# Java - Deserialize nested json to object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

I have problems to deserialize some nested Json.

The json : [JSON LINK HERE](https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json)

To deserialize :

And the two classes :

I'm getting this Exception :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code for deserializing this json. Include the Objects that you're trying to deserialize it into and show how you're calling the object mapper.

Answer (score -1):

suppose you have missed two properties in your `RandomBixi Class`.

```
class RandomBixi {
@JsonProperty("id")
int id;
@JsonProperty("s")
String nom;
@JsonProperty("n")
int idTerminal;
@JsonProperty("st")
int etatStation;
@JsonProperty("b")
boolean bloque;
@JsonProperty("su")
boolean suspendue;
@JsonProperty("m")
boolean hs;
@JsonProperty("lu")
int lu;
@JsonProperty("lc")
int lc;
@JsonProperty("bk")
boolean bk;
@JsonProperty("bl")
boolean bl;
@JsonProperty("la")
String latitude;
@JsonProperty("lo")
String longitude;
@JsonProperty("da")
int borneDispo;
@JsonProperty("dx")
int dx;
@JsonProperty("ba")
int bixiDispo;
@JsonProperty("bx")
int bx;

  getters ans setters....
}
```

If you don't want all the properties to be mapped use `@JsonIgnore` on the property.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. i still get the same error on the same line.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the stack-trace of the exception.

Comment: have you added `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on `ListRandomBixi class` and tried.

Comment: I think `lu` and `lc` are out of java `int` range. suppose you change there type for suitable type `long` or `String` based on your requirement.